# Skills generated on-the-fly disappear

Tags: webforms

I have a weird situation with the Webform module.

I'm working on a project bidding website, and for this purpose we have got a webform available as a block. The company who built the website made it so that skills grid on the webform are generated on-the-fly, based on the project's requirements. Here is where the problem starts. I accidentally deleted that node, then re-created it; hence the nid change. I then modified the nid in the database in every possible table I could think of. I also renamed and edited the tpl file to match the new nid. Now, when we apply for a project and leave a required field out, it normally should warn me without leaving the project node; which is the case on my development server. However, this is NOT the case on my production server. As I am 100% sure the solution lies in the database (I confirmed this), I suggest transferring the complete database from dev to prod; however the owner of the project raises an objection. So I transferred webform related tables to no avail; then transferred context tables, again no.

What could this issue?

Comment: I don't understand the last phrase (question) here, consider re-editing your question to rephrase it. Also, try to enhance this part of your question (near the end) also: "however the owner of the project raises an objection. So I transferred webform related tables to no avail; then transferred context tables, again no.". That might help to actually get an answer to your question ... (something I'm considering after I beter understand the question).